# Determine RAM type in debian server

Tags: linux, memory, hardware

How can I determine the *exact* specs of the RAM modules in my server while the server continues to run?

I have a server with three 2GB sticks of DDR2 running a custom linux distro based on debian.   I'd like to bump this up to 4 2GB sticks and gain dual-channel mode while I'm at it.  That means I need to make sure I get a new stick that's a precise match for what's already there.  I'd rather not take this particular server offline to visually inspect the RAM.  From prior inspection during downtime I do at least know that I have two sticks of HP branded RAM and one stick of Samsung, and I know that the server shipped stock with the Samsung and the HP was ordered later (which seems odd, but it's the way it is).

This server is cli-only (no real gui), and I can't find docs from the original purchase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would try the following command which might you give you the information you need depending on the motherboard:

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory
```

For example on one of my Dell servers I get the part number (but no so lucky on my workstation):

```
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x1000
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 72 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 2048 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: 1
        Locator: DIMM_A2 
        Bank Locator: Not Specified
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1066 MHz (0.9 ns)
        Manufacturer: 00CE000080CE
        Serial Number: 423C357E
        Asset Tag: 01101700
        Part Number: M391B5673FH0-CF8
```

Comment: Bummer - manufacturer and part number came back "not specified".  This was a good suggestion, though.

Comment: The one thing I did learn is that it's running at 1332 mhz (probably a rounding error from 1333), and I was probably mistaken and it's ddr3 instead (and no complaints about that :)

Answer (score 3):

How about using lshw?

http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter

http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter#Exampleoutput

http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=lshw

Comment: Second thing that came to my mind would be using IPMI standard to poll HW status if you are running on some known brand.

Comment: +1 for the lshw link. Hnady little summary, that.